# (Firebase Authen ) Sign out and intent from Fragment to MainActivity doesn't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, firebase-authentication

```
class ProfileActivity : AppCompatActivity() {   << on xml file has sign out Button

    var mAuth: FirebaseAuth? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile)

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

        btn_signout.setOnClickListener() {
                mAuth!!.signOut()
                var intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            }


        }
    }



class ChatActivity : AppCompatActivity() {   << activity's using NavbatListener for fragment.

    private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {item->
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.nav_chat -> {
                println("home pressed")
                replaceFragment(ChatFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  true
            }
            R.id.nav_contact -> {
                println("contact pressed")
                replaceFragment(ContactFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  true
            }
            R.id.nav_position -> {
                println("position pressed")
                replaceFragment(PositionFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  true
            }
            R.id.nav_profile -> {
                println("profile pressed")
                replaceFragment(ProfileFragment())
                return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener  true
            }


        }
            false
    }

    private  fun  replaceFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
        fragmentTransaction.commit()
    }



    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat)

        bottomNavigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
        replaceFragment(ChatFragment())

    }


}
```

I have a botton "btn_signout"on Fragment and i want to sign out to MainActivity by intent.

it works if i use on "option menu" but I want do with a simple button .

I am new.  Thanks for help

Comment: The button in an Activity, not in a Fragment!

Answer (score 0):

Change `this` to `getActivity()` in your intent. Like this:

```
   var intent = Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity::class.java) 
   getActivity().startActivity(intent)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are doing this from fragment and going to activity you've to do like this:

```
 btnSignOutAccount.setOnClickListener {
                    AuthUI.getInstance().signOut(this@YourFragmentName.context!!)
                        .addOnCompleteListener {
                            startActivity(intentFor<YourActivityName>().newTask().clearTask())
                        }
                }
```

above anko library is used to precise the code for intent purpose, here is the code with standard way:

```
 val intent = Intent(this@YourFragmentName, YourActivityName::class.java).apply {
                    flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
                }
                startActivity(intent)
```

just replace it with your addOnCompleteListener block's code.
In case you are wondering about this flag, it clears the state of previous activity which means if you press back accidentally it's not gonna take you back again in your login activity or whatever activity you've signOut from.